# regex, match a substring within a string

Tags: regex, string

I want to a capture a string with this regex:

```
^([\d]_[a-z|A-Z]+_test)$
```

So it would capture something like: `1_mytest_test`

However, if the string is within another string like:

```
results.1_mytest_test.=fail, more info
```

There is no match.

I thought the `^` and `$` would demarcate the beginning and end of the string that I am looking for, right?

Comment: Remove `^` and `$`, and `|`.

Comment: Oh, wow but why is that?

Comment: `\b\d_[a-zA-Z]+_test\b`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should remove the `^`/`$` anchors, and you need no `|` inside the character class if you do not need to match a literal `|` with the regex:

```
\d_[a-zA-Z]+_test
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vU4vF1/1)

The `^` is a start of string anchor, and `$` is an end of string anchor, thus, they "anchor" the string you match at its start and end.

As for `|`, a character class matches a *single character*. `[a-zA-Z]` matches 1 letter. No need in the alternation operator `|` here since it is treated literally (i.e. the `[a-zA-Z|]` will match `|` symbol in the input string).

Just FYI: in many cases, when you need something to be matched *inside* a larger string, you need to use word boundaries `\b` to match whole words:

```
\b\d_[a-zA-Z]+_test\b
```

However, people often have non-word characters in patterns, then you'd be safer with look-arounds (not sure your engine supports look-behind, but here is a version for, say, PCRE):

```
(?<!\w)\d_[a-zA-Z]+_test(?!\w)
```

Comment: But doesn't the `^` and `$` demarcate the beginning and end of string I want to match?

Comment: The caret (`^`) tells the regex engine to start looking for a digit (`\d`) at the beginning, and then match all subpatterns from left to right and the `_test` must be at the end of the string. Or a line, if you specify the `/m` (multiline) modifier.

Comment: I also added some more fun details :) Have a great day!